# End(xlDown) not copy entire data from column if you have blank cells

Tags: vba

I have the following problem:

I have a funtion that copy paste columns from another sheet to another based on header, but when the macro start to copy data it stops to the fist blank line instead of going to the end.
I also tried to use many .End(xlDown)....but...how many I can be used..:))

any sugestion?

```
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z1")
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim k As Long       
k = Range("B:B").End(xlDown)

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(k)).Copy      Destination:=Worksheets("RAW").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next

End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
Dim headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("RAW").Range("A1:Z1")
GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)),               Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Each Excel sheet contains a [UsedRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) object.  You can use this to find out how many rows need to be copied.

**Example**

```
' Returns the final row with content.
Sub NumberOfRowsInPlay()

    MsgBox ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub
```

I tested against a worksheet that had a value in just one cell (A5).  It returned 5.

Comment: Ok, but how should I integrated?    In my first note I give "k" value as a range in column B and end(xlDown) and after that I put "k" instead of "xldwone". in the below formula

Comment: If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(k)).Copy         Destination:=Worksheets("RAW").Cells(2,   GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End If